# Integral Method to find upper and lower bounds on the sum

Tags: definite-integrals, approximate-integration

I got this problem wrong on my exam and I know why I got it wrong but I am not sure how to find the right answer.

This is the question:
Consider$\sum_{k=1}^n (3+ 2/k^3)$. Use the integral method to obtain upper and lower bound on the sum. Do not split the summation into $\sum_{k=1}^n 3+\sum_{k=1}^n ( 2/k^3)$

This is the formula we had to use: [Click here to see the approximation integral formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arbA3.png)

This function is decreasing and I was able to calculate the lower bound, but I am not sure how to do the upper bound becuase this is what I get $ \int_{0}^{n}$(3+2/k^3)dx and after taking the antiderivative. I get 3k - (1/k^2) from 0 to n. so if I take the integral from 0 to n then 1/k^2 becomes undefined. I tried to change the integral from -1 to n but I got it wrong on the exam.

Could someone please tell me how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(3+\frac1{k^3} \right)&=\left(3+\frac1{1^3} \right)+\sum_{k=\color{red}{2}}^n\left(3+\frac1{k^3} \right)
\\\\&\le \left(3+\frac1{1^3}\right)+\int_{\color{red}{2-1}}^n\left(3+\frac1{x^3} \right)dx
\end{align}
$$ then getting easily an *upper bound*.

Comment: thanks! Will I need to calculate the derivative of 5 in the integration part or just take the derivative of what's inside the summation and then multiply by 5? Also, for the lower bound, I can use the original summation without changing the bounds?